# How to strip the beginning of an URL before passing it to the handler in a htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my .htacess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteRule ^ /trunk/web/app.php [L]
```

At the moment, my PHP controller receives the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and I want to strip the `/api` part from this URI before passing it to the PHP controller.

How can I do?

Comment: You can not change the value of `%{REQUEST_URI}` from htaccess this way. Isn't it possible to do in php?

Comment: I'm using Symfony, I guess it's possible to define a base URI, but this would force me to have a different file on the development env and on the production env. My .htaccess is on development environment only, and I'm looking for a solution that implies modifying this .htaccess only

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to add the route as a query parameter and get it in php with 
`$_GET['route']`.

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ /trunk/web/app.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does Symfony take this kind of URL with the route as a parameter? If not, it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: This might not work with symfony. You could also try to redirect to a new url with RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Yes this works but it duplicates all of the http requests